# SQL query maximum and minimum value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am facing some problem in my sql query.

I have a table table_name with the following fields: id, zip, size. There are 3 entry in this table and entry for 'zip' fields are 2001, 2005, 2009 and 'size' value is 5 for all the three entry. And i want the maximum and minimum value of field as per my search.

When i search any value between 2001 and 2009 then query gets the perfect result as per query.

Example: if i search field value 2003 then it gives both the minimum value 2001 and maximum value 2005.

But when i search any value less than 2001 or greater than 2009 then it gives empty result.

Can anyone please tell me what mistake i have done in my query.

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` 
WHERE `size` LIKE ('%5%') 
  AND (`zip` in (SELECT max(`zip`) 
                 FROM `table_name` 
                 WHERE `zip` < '2010' 
                 order by `zip` desc) 
    OR `zip` in (SELECT min(`zip`) 
                 FROM `table_name` 
                 WHERE `zip` > '2010' 
                 order by `zip` asc)
      )
```

Comment: Is the 'zip' field a number or char field? Also, what datatype is the 'size' field?

Comment: You have tagged with `MySQL`, `SQL-Server`, and `SQL-Server-2008`, but this looks suspiciously like `MySQL` syntax. Which DBMS are you actually using?

Comment: This should return 2009 when searching for 2010. If not it might be due to wrong data types. Btw, you don't need ORDER BY in the Scalar Subqueries.

Comment: Yes, the ORDER BYs in subqueries don't work in SQL Server.

Comment: Your query seems to work as expected for me. In this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf976a/1) 1 row is returned with your query (2009) using both int and varchar types for `zip`. Have you posted the exact query that is causing you problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all for sharing your thoughts.

At last i find the mistake of my query.  I used `LIKE ('%5%')` in my query, for this bracket `()` it created a problem. So i just remove the brackets form `LIKE` and  also added `LIKE '%5%'` condition into the inner queries.

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `size` LIKE '%5%' AND (`zip` in (SELECT max(`zip`) FROM `table_name` WHERE `zip` < '2010' AND `size` LIKE '%5%' order by `zip` desc) OR `zip` in (SELECT min(`zip`)  FROM `table_name` WHERE `zip` > '2010' AND `size` LIKE '%5%' order by `zip` asc))
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be related to datatype. You do > and < criteria on string values. I would suggest to convert them to integer values first